# To track the changes in a view on daily basis

Tags: sql-server-2005

How could I get the changes (data) in a view between a certain period of time. Changes like new rows, updated rows or deleted rows.  I am making a stored proc which has to detect the changes in a huge view and then sync them with another table on daily basis.  I dont want to to scan all rows when I know the changed rows will be less than 1% daily.

Thanks.

Comment: How big are you talking?

Comment: You mean the size of table/view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is going to change when the underlying data changes. You need to detect changes in the columns in the tables that are in the view - you will probably need triggers on that column that will fire a stored procedure that reconstructs the SELECT query the view is using, and then update the other table as necessary.

Comment: I wanted to do it without triggers. Thought there might be some hidden SQL server object which could give me images of the view to be compared based on timelines. Was this question so silly to deserve a downvote?

Comment: Don't know about the downvote, but SQL Server to my knowledge does not track or audit changes to views in any way. Triggers are it when it comes to that kind of auditing.

Comment: @Wil is correct, there is no internal tracking.  The overhead of tracking in that way would be ridiculous.

Comment: If the view is indexded, in which case it will always contain data (and not just at run time), I could use the triggers in the view itself. Isn't it?

Comment: You can only use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on a view.